# How do I make a hidden div ease out from the top instead of from the left using .show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I am trying to animate my navigation menu to bounce in from the top when it reaches a certain anchor point. I am currently using the .show()/.hide() to accomplish this, but it only eases in from the left. I tried to incorporate .animate() into it with no luck.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var t = $("#about").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= t ) {
        $('#global-nav').show(500, 'easeOutBounce');
    } else {
        $('#global-nav').hide(500, 'easeInExpo');
    }  
});
```

```css
html { 
  height: 2000px; 
} 
#global-nav {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#about{
   margin-top:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="global-nav"></div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

I am using the jQuery Easing plugin and have the current code functional here, just scroll down to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/0oazqj4y/30/

Is there an option for .show() to specify the ease in direction or do I need to incorporate the .animate() some how? I am fairly new to jQuery and have been working on this all day to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .SlideDown() function in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. This is perfect, thanks! I tried to add this to my site, but for some reason the easing animation isn't working. Do you know of anything that could interfere with it? If not, no worries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using slide() or its variants. Here's an example with slide down to show and slide up to hide:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= t ) {
        $('#global-nav').slideDown(500, 'easeOutBounce');
    } else {
        $('#global-nav').slideUp(500, 'easeInExpo');
    }       
});
```